# C++ how to print line and line number?

Tags: c++

I want to get the line number as a variable to use with my code, which is reading line by line and then returns the line. Then add `LINE [LINENUMBER]:`  before each line

```cpp
ifstream f(argv[1]);
string line;
string linenumber; // or use int instead if you wan't, doesn't matter. 

while (getline(f, line)) {
    cout << "LINE " + linenumber; + ": " + line << endl;
}
```

Comment: Why is linenumber a std::string instead of an int?

Comment: `ine linenumber = 0; while (getline(f, line)) { linenumber ++; ....`?

Comment: You need a counter for your line numbers. Maybe use parser generators like [ANTLR](https://antlr.org/)

Comment: What about `string line;
int linenumber =1;
while (getline(f, line)) {
    cout << "LINE " << linenumber++ << ":" <<  line << endl;
}`

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
string line;
int line_number = 1;

while (getline(f, line)) {
  cout << "LINE [" << line_number ++ << "]: " << line << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
ifstream f(argv[1]);
string line;
int linenumber; 

while (getline(f, line)) {
    cout << "LINE " + linenumber; + ": " + line << endl;
    linenumber++;
}
```

from the way your code looks, I assume you are trying to find how many lines are in some stream... there are much better and faster ways to do so if that is the case.

Comment: If you do copy and paste other answers and omments, then do not forget to initialize linenumber with 1. Otherwise your copy and paste will not work . .